# Any video or audio misses the few first couple of seconds; I must scroll back to the beginning to see/hear the first few seconds

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, video

When I play any media (audio or video) in any software, the first two or three seconds are skipped. The media starts at 00:02 or 00:03 or so. The only way to access the first few seconds is to manually scroll the slider back to the beginning of the timeline, and replay.
If a list is being played, this bug happens only for the first song. The rest start correctly at 00:00.

I don't know if this annoying bug is a driver thing or what else. I uninstalled, reinstalled, and updated the sound and GPU drivers to no avail. This happens with any media (any video format, any audio format), played by any player software, from any hardware device (hard disks, USBs, anything). This has been happening at least for the last couple of years (before that, I hadn't noticed and don't know).

This bug also happens for any streamed media (e.g., YouTube).

The hardware is fully tested and working 100%. All drivers (video, sound, etc.) are fully updated to the latest version.

- Computer: Acer Aspire V5-573G laptop running Windows 10
- CPU: Intel Core i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz X64
- GPUs: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M (4GB RAM), Intel HD Graphics Family (1GB RAM).
- Audio: Sound Card Intel Display Audio, Sound Card High Definition Audio Device

Edit:

- This problem persists even after setting the Power Plan to "High Performance" and disabling any battery-saver option in any settings I could find (including Video Playback settings).
- I am not using any headphones at all (wireless or else).
- I am not using (and have not ever used) any Remote Desktop applications.

**SOLVED**:

The laptop's hardware and software are just fine. The problem is my (old) Panasonic TV, connected to the laptop via HDMI.

Because:

- The bug does not exist when the media is directly played on the laptop's speakers.
- The bug happens only when the laptop is connected to my Panasonic TV via HDMI.
- It happens regardless of the sound device in use: either the Panasonic TV's speakers or a headphone connected to the Panasonic TV.
- The bug doesn't happen at all when the same HDMI is connected to another TV. So the problem is not with the HDMI set, but only with the Panasonic TV.

Comment: This sounds like your sounddriver is closed. This usually happens if you use a service such as Remote Desktop, but should not happen normally. Do you RDP into another computer by any chance? If its not RDP, then you can try setting your Energy Profile to High Performance, rather than Balanced. It could also be that your display does some powersaver. See if you can disable that from the display menu.

Comment: Are you using a wireless headset by any chance?

Comment: @LPChip thanks a lot. No, I don't RDP into another computer. Never used Remote Desktop either as the receiver or the controller parties. I just set the power plan to "High Performance", but the problem persisted. I couldn't find any powersaver options in the display settings. But I could find an "Optimize for battery life" in the Battery Options of Video Playback settings; I set it to "Optimize for video quality". The problem remains. I also made sure the charger is plugged in, to no avail.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks. No, I don't use any wireless headphones.

Comment: What device are you outputting sound to, some kind of speakers or something else? How are they connected to the computer? Just trying to rule out other devices.

Comment: What speakers are you using? This sounds like a speakers problem. When you have stationary speakers that are connected to AC, you can often hear a small buzz when you turn up the volume to maximum but play no sound at all. That's because there is some noise in the cable. Some speakers however (mainly portable ones) turn themselves off when they don't recognize any input signal and it takes a while for them to turn on when you play a sound. This happens when I use my JBL Charge 4, even if it's connect via AUX cable not bluetooth.

Comment: @Mokubai you and randomiStack847 solved the problem! My sound device was a Panasonic TV connected via HDMI to the PC. Once I disconnected the HDMI and played the media on my laptop's own speakers, it worked like a charm. No missing first seconds anymore. ---

Comment: @randomStack847 --- By the way, when connected to the TV, the problem exists regardless of the sound output device (either the TV's speakers or a conventional headphone connected to the TV by wire). ---  Is the Panasonic TV the culprit or is it the HDMI (for example, GPU driver problems, etc)? The Panasonic TV is the problem, because I connected the same HDMI cable to a second TV, and it again worked just fine (no skipping the first seconds). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vic have a look in your TV settings for volume compensation or "dynamic range" or settings related to audio delay. That was kind of where I was heading to, that somehow your device receiving audio was doing something *odd*, and I was thinking more about bluetooth speakers which I've seen can have power saving that can mean they take a second or two to "wake up" when audio starts playing and it seems your TV has it too. randomStack847 actually summed it up, but that was what I was pressing towards...

Comment: @Mokubai thanks a lot. When LPchip told me about power, I remembered that last year I had read about this "waking up" procedure and that I had played with my laptop's power options and sound drivers to get rid of this waking up thing (of course, to no avail). I am glad that now I know the laptop is intact; the confusion is over. I was mostly annoyed by "**not knowing**" why it is happening despite all the tweaks and troubleshooting. Otherwise, 1 or 2 seconds of skipping is not in itself *that* annoying. I can use a new TV or ignore the bug altogether.

Comment: @Mokubai No, the TV didn't have any settings to turn off that "waking up" thing. I checked them and there were no options other than very basic sound options. I played with all of them, and none resolved this bug. The TV is ancient (about 20-some years old), so I wouldn't expect much flexibility and control from its very basic user interface.

Comment: Fair enough, at least you know your laptop is working as it should. As you know it is something about your TV you could potentially use Audacity to create some very low level white noise audio and have a program constantly playing it in the background which might trick the TV or audio output to stay on. I'd recommend you posting your "solved" section as an answer as you can at least mark it an solved that way.

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai . I hate any background processes unless they are very necessary. Besides I don't mind that 1 or 2 seconds, now that I know what it is. So I prefer not to run such background noises. Sure, I will add it. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

The laptop's hardware and software are just fine. The problem is my (old) Panasonic TV, connected to the laptop via HDMI.

Because:

- The bug does not exist when the media is directly played on the laptop's speakers.
- The bug happens only when the laptop is connected to my Panasonic TV via HDMI.
- It happens regardless of the sound device in use: either the Panasonic TV's speakers or a headphone connected to the Panasonic TV.
- The bug doesn't happen at all when the same HDMI is connected to another TV. So the problem is not with the HDMI set, but only with the Panasonic TV.